# render_template does nothing after receiving ajax content (flask, python, javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, web, flask

I am passing data with ajax to my python function when a condition is met:

```
        if (lesson.length === 0) {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:'POST',
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    dataType:'json',
                    url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/result?value=' + errors ,
                    success:function(response){ document.write(response); }  
                }
            );
        }
```

I know that the information is correctly received, since I can see it in the terminal through print:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020 11:59:46] "GET /static/flexjava.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
0
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Aug/2020 11:59:48] "POST /result?value=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But python does nothing after the print() function. Render or redirect both don't work, the browser stays just as it is even though the information was passed:

```
@app.route("/result", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def result():
    content = request.args.get('value')
    if "username" not in session or session["username"] == "guest":
        return redirect("/login")
    if request.method == "GET":
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        print(content)
        return render_template("finished.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using ajax properly.  You want to receive back a `json` response, not a complete web page.

Try:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type:'POST',
            contentType:'application/json',
            dataType:'json',
            url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/result?value=' + errors ,
            success:function(response){ 
                console.log(response);
                document.write(response); # not a good idea
                # I would use something like:
                # document.getElementById("myDiv").innerText = response.content;
            }  
        }
    );
```

Then:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route("/result", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def result():
    content = request.args.get('value')
    ...
    else:
        print(content)
        return jsonify(
            {
                "content": content
            }
        )
```

This functionality really does nothing, as you already have `errors` in the calling template.  If you are trying to go to `finished`, you would do that in the ajax `success` callback:

```
success:function(response){ 
    console.log(response);
    window.location.replace(window.location.href + "finished");
}
```